# Is it possible to add approval independently for individual matrix workflows?

Tags: yaml, github-actions, cicd

I am working with GitHub Actions. I have a matrix workflow and I could add a environment that I can approve before deploying. I am looking for adding approval for individual workflows of the matrix workflow.

For example, if the matrix has 3 values, there will be three workflows. Now, I can approve all 3 at once. is it possible to approve the workflows separately?

I tried to add approvers and min-approval in the reusable workflow but the result is not as expected.

Reusable workflow:

```
name: Reusing workflow demo

on:
  workflow_call:
    inputs:
      username:
        description: 'A username passed from the caller workflow'
        default: 'usernamedemo'
        required: false
        type: string
      approvers:
        description: Required approvers
        required: true
        type: string
      minimum-approvals:
        description: Minimum number of approvals to progress workflow
        required: true
        type: number
    
jobs:
  reusable_workflow_job:
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    environment: Production
   
    steps:
      - name: Print the input name to STDOUT
        run: echo The username is ${{ inputs.username }}
```

Caller workflow

```
name: Caller workflow demo

on: push
    
jobs:
  call-workflow:
    strategy:
      matrix:
        names: [user1, user2, user3]
    uses: ./.github/workflows/reusable-workflow.yml
    with:
      username: ${{matrix.names}}
      approvers: user1
      minimum-approvals: 1
```

Comment: I don't fully understand the requirements you're trying to solve. In GitHub Actions approvals and approval configuration is done at the environment level. You can't configure these natively for generic workflow jobs. There are 3rd party actions that "hack" this feature, you might be able to use those: https://github.com/marketplace/actions/manual-workflow-approval & https://github.com/marketplace?type=actions&query=manual+approval+

Comment: Thanks. I looked into the link but a bit unsure if there is anyway I can use it without docker image?